# +Tx +Rx -Tx -Rx Connectivity

Tags: ethernet

I have a sensor that I am trying to connect to via an ethernet cable. The sensors pinout gives

> "Signal Name:" +TX +RX -TX -RX.

My assumption would be to hook up:

> +TX to +RX (ethernet pin: 3)
>   +RX to +TX(pin 1)
>   -TX to -RX(pin 6)
>   -RX to -TX(pin 2)

I have also tried swapping polarity +TX to -RX... but to no avail.

The sensors manual says everything should be in DHCP mode and should discover within a minute.

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What sensor? If it is Ethernet, how do the tags serial and rs232 have anything to do with this?

Comment: Are you wiring this as cross-over or straight through? Please fix your tags, I don't see how this applies to either serial or RS232...

Comment: Hello, sorry for the misleading tags, just my lack of knowledge showing through. But @Justme, it is an Omron OS32C laser scanner.

Comment: A normal patch-thru cable to 4 wire  Tx+ to Tx+  etc , I expect  https://kxiwq67737.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/4208iED2AF6CAE2097C87/image-dimensions/592x490?v=1.0  not a crossover cable

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, why don't you put this comment as the answer?

Comment: A normal ethernet cable does NOT cross the TX and RX pins -- TX+ goes to TX+ and so forth.

I'm a bit confused why you're running into this at all -- normally the device would have a network jack, and you would plug in an ordinary network cable at both ends. Why are you needing to worry about pinouts?

Comment: @Glenn Willen Because in Ethernet, there's something called medium dependent interface and medium dependent interface crossover. A medium dependent interface can only communicate with a medium dependent interface crossover. Two medium dependent interfaces cannot communicate with each-other. Same goes for medium dependent interface crossovers, two cannot communicate directly. Back in the day, the idea was, that you'd connect say a PC using MDI to a switch using MDI-X, and all would work fine, but connection between two PCs would need the cross-over cable. cont

Comment: @Glenn Willen Today, many Ethernet PHYs have the Auto MDI/MDI-X feature, and can auto-negotiate which side should be MDI and which MDI-X, but there are still devices, where, due to reasons, something like that has not been implemented, and it's important to know, if the interface is MDI or MDI-X, which makes the whole Rx/Tx story important.

Comment: That's all fine but why is OP running into this? I would expect that at worst OP could buy a crossover patch cable if need be, and either way not have to worry about individual wires.

Comment: If OP _is_ dealing with individual pins for some reason there are more questions that need to be answered -- principally, does the transceiver in the sensor come with magnetics, or do those need to be added? Either way, if the sensor doesn't come with a jack, OP should probably be adding a jack to it and not trying to wire it up directly to a cable or something.

Comment: @Glenn Willen Hi there, the jack on the sensor is a 4 pin M-12 connector. The OEM makes a cable but I'm sure it's expensive and has a lead time. Will keep trying thanks for all the info!!

Answer (score 1):

A normal patch-thru 1-to-1 cable   4-wire Tx+ to Tx+ etc , is what I would expect , not a crossover cable, Tx+ to Rx+ etc.

I believe this is the M12 D-coded 4-wire assignment, although I have never used these myself.  These should be 100BASE-Tx <s>RS485</s> 4-wire physical interface signal levels.

[image]

Comment: .Good answer. Standard M12 to 8P8C cables for industrial Ethernet are available for purchase. Though Ethernet would not have RS485 levels (well, at least the most common versions of 100M and Gigabit versions don't).

Comment: Right . 100BASE-Tx supported

Comment: Tony, can you tell us where you found this nice graphic?

Comment: I just google imaged it > community.Cisco "The topic you are trying to access is not available. "  Wayback Machine doesn't have that page archived.